# Unable to install java on my ubuntu

Tags: java

Whenever I try to install java on my Ubuntu, it show error like
Package dependencies cannot be resolved.

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Comment: What happens when you enter `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`? Please edit you question and give us the full error message. We need them to diagnose the problem

Comment: Which Java are you trying to install? Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: when i try to run this command sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre, then i get error like this 
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
and also when i run this sudo apt-get update
the error is
GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

Comment: and when i try it install it from ubuntu software center , then error like this 
ca-certificates-java icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgif4 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0 libnss3-1d liborbit2 openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata tzdata-java

Answer (score 1):

If u need to install the Oracle Java Download it from the official site from this link

[Oracle Java Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Follow This step to get install

Replace the Version Value Of your downloaded version with were ever jdk1.7.0_21 i have used

```
#java -version

#sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo mv jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm

#cd /usr/lib/jvm

#sudo tar zxvf jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz

#sudo rm jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz

#ls -l

#jdk1.7.0_21

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java" 1

#sudo update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javac"

#sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java"

#sudo vi /etc/profile

Add the following entries to the bottom of your /etc/profile file:

#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export JAVA_HOME export PATH

#. /etc/profile

#java -version
```

Hope tthis Will Fix your issue ...

Comment: Even though it is nice you took your time and effort to copy & paste your install instructions, there I take some issues with them: 1) It doesn't account for future versions for Java 1.7, in fact it is already outdated since Java 1.7.40 is the current version. 2) It leaves the person following your instruction in the dark about what you are doing. 3) The formatting needs improvements. You are mixing commands an comments. 4) Also, explain why you suggest the proprietary JDK if the open-JDK or even open-JRE could do?

Comment: @MadMike sometimes Oracle's java is just *better* (being the original Java). It runs Minecraft better, for one. I've always used Oracle Java without a problem (whilst I'd prefer FOSS if it would work as well)

Comment: @minerz029 i work with Oracle Java every day. I don't question its merrits. But with that OP, is the additional complexity really waranten?